# Кастомный балун в полигоне

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Подскажите, почему в этом коде карты выдают ошибку:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setPosition' of null

```js
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
            center: [59.951671, 30.330581],
            zoom: 10
        }, {
            searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
        }),
  
  // Создание макета балуна на основе Twitter Bootstrap.
        MyBalloonLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
            '<div class="popover top">' +
                '<a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>' +
                '<div class="arrow"></div>' +
                '<div class="popover-inner">' +
                '$[[options.contentLayout observeSize minWidth=235 maxWidth=235 maxHeight=350]]' +
                '</div>' +
                '</div>', {
                /**
                 * Строит экземпляр макета на основе шаблона и добавляет его в родительский HTML-элемент.
                 * @see https://api.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/layout.templateBased.Base.xml#build
                 * @function
                 * @name build
                 */
                build: function () {
                    this.constructor.superclass.build.call(this);

                    this._$element = $('.popover', this.getParentElement());

                    this.applyElementOffset();

                    this._$element.find('.close')
                        .on('click', $.proxy(this.onCloseClick, this));
                },

                /**
                 * Удаляет содержимое макета из DOM.
                 * @see https://api.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/layout.templateBased.Base.xml#clear
                 * @function
                 * @name clear
                 */
                clear: function () {
                    this._$element.find('.close')
                        .off('click');

                    this.constructor.superclass.clear.call(this);
                },

                /**
                 * Метод будет вызван системой шаблонов АПИ при изменении размеров вложенного макета.
                 * @see https://api.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/IBalloonLayout.xml#event-userclose
                 * @function
                 * @name onSublayoutSizeChange
                 */
                onSublayoutSizeChange: function () {
                    MyBalloonLayout.superclass.onSublayoutSizeChange.apply(this, arguments);

                    if(!this._isElement(this._$element)) {
                        return;
                    }

                    this.applyElementOffset();

                    this.events.fire('shapechange');
                },

                /**
                 * Сдвигаем балун, чтобы "хвостик" указывал на точку привязки.
                 * @see https://api.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/IBalloonLayout.xml#event-userclose
                 * @function
                 * @name applyElementOffset
                 */
                applyElementOffset: function () {
                    this._$element.css({
                        left: -(this._$element[0].offsetWidth / 2),
                        top: -(this._$element[0].offsetHeight + this._$element.find('.arrow')[0].offsetHeight)
                    });
                },

                /**
                 * Закрывает балун при клике на крестик, кидая событие "userclose" на макете.
                 * @see https://api.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/IBalloonLayout.xml#event-userclose
                 * @function
                 * @name onCloseClick
                 */
                onCloseClick: function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();

                    this.events.fire('userclose');
                },

                /**
                 * Используется для автопозиционирования (balloonAutoPan).
                 * @see https://api.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/ILayout.xml#getClientBounds
                 * @function
                 * @name getClientBounds
                 * @returns {Number[][]} Координаты левого верхнего и правого нижнего углов шаблона относительно точки привязки.
                 */
                getShape: function () {
                    if(!this._isElement(this._$element)) {
                        return MyBalloonLayout.superclass.getShape.call(this);
                    }

                    var position = this._$element.position();

                    return new ymaps.shape.Rectangle(new ymaps.geometry.pixel.Rectangle([
                        [position.left, position.top], [
                            position.left + this._$element[0].offsetWidth,
                            position.top + this._$element[0].offsetHeight + this._$element.find('.arrow')[0].offsetHeight
                        ]
                    ]));
                },

                /**
                 * Проверяем наличие элемента (в ИЕ и Опере его еще может не быть).
                 * @function
                 * @private
                 * @name _isElement
                 * @param {jQuery} [element] Элемент.
                 * @returns {Boolean} Флаг наличия.
                 */
                _isElement: function (element) {
                    return element && element[0] && element.find('.arrow')[0];
                }
            });
   
    BalloonContentLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
            '<div style="margin: 10px;">11111</div>'); 

    // Создаем многоугольник, используя класс GeoObject.
    var myGeoObject = new ymaps.GeoObject({
        // Описываем геометрию геообъекта.
        geometry: {
            // Тип геометрии - "Многоугольник".
            type: "Polygon",
            // Указываем координаты вершин многоугольника.
            coordinates: [
                // Координаты вершин внешнего контура.
                [
                   [ 59.98050787316514 ,30.276271287380787],
                    [59.981411135142736,30.28348106521282 ],
                    [59.981626193875776,30.287600938259637],
                    [59.98188426251403 ,30.291720811306554],
                    [59.98188426251403 ,30.297213975369072],
                    [59.981196075016896,30.303393784939374],
                    [59.97981965695854 ,30.31197685378703 ],
                    [59.97878730573293 ,30.31747001784952 ],
                    [59.97689457792983 ,30.32364982741985 ],
                    [59.97448549461692 ,30.327426377712822],
                    [59.97173204119555 ,30.33017295974407 ],
                    [59.969150469982154,30.332232896267502],
                    [59.96605231800164 ,30.334292832790936],
                    [59.964374030930564,30.334807816921803],
                    [59.962609585874226,30.33497947829875 ],
                    [59.959166494762414,30.335322801052666],
                    [59.95606740577672 ,30.336524430691316],
                    [59.954259469567496,30.33798355239539 ],
                    [59.95210703552669 ,30.33017295974407 ],
                    [59.95098771437923 ,30.324593964993053],
                    [59.94969614286743 ,30.321246568142495],
                    [59.94780174662443 ,30.31747001784952 ],
                    [59.94780174662443 ,30.31300682204876 ],
                    [59.94676839379639 ,30.309573594509676],
                    [59.94422793069265 ,30.307341996609296],
                    [59.941428889282946,30.306827012478433],
                    [59.94022307529868 ,30.301677171169832],
                    [59.937983589740675,30.29481071609172 ],
                    [59.93712220873366 ,30.290347520290933],
                    [59.93626080527731 ,30.286227647244065],
                    [59.93501173038011 ,30.280820313870045],
                    [59.933331865599165,30.27764457839641 ],
                    [59.93057497940691 ,30.272838059841728],
                    [59.92816251538927 ,30.27009147781046 ],
                    [59.92488817551137 ,30.267344895779214],
                    [59.92187204927931 ,30.26597160476359 ],
                    [59.91971750499295 ,30.264598313747967],
                    [59.91868327387625 ,30.26082176345499 ],
                    [59.91868327386725 ,30.258332673489193],
                    [59.91902802117505 ,30.25567192214642 ],
                    [59.92001914963477 ,30.251981202541867],
                    [59.92161351138359 ,30.24743217605266 ],
                    [59.922302941304906,30.241939011990166],
                    [59.924026453231384,30.23816246169719 ],
                    [59.92523285813594 ,30.234385911404217],
                    [59.926094548979066,30.23129600661905 ],
                    [59.92816251538927 ,30.227176133572183],
                    [59.928679486783494,30.222026292263585],
                    [59.929541087802285,30.21807808059364 ],
                    [59.93117806789334 ,30.21395820754677 ],
                    [59.932125756161206,30.21138328689247 ],
                    [59.93464561326022 ,30.2106537260404],
                    [59.93750983293789 ,30.20992416518835 ],
                    [59.94028767356927 ,30.207048837124447],
                    [59.9436250802578  ,30.204001847683518],
                    [59.947812510508044,30.203658524929523],
                    [59.95055719613177 ,30.204774323879725],
                    [59.95322631871933 ,30.206920091091686],
                    [59.95580913521645 ,30.20820755141876 ],
                    [59.95843479162023 ,30.210439149319214],
                    [59.96123239250762 ,30.21378654616985 ],
                    [59.963212089909675,30.21618980544715 ],
                    [59.96656869684799 ,30.21618980544715 ],
                    [59.96966680036843 ,30.21515983718547 ],
                    [59.972011699266595,30.21361488479285 ],
                    [59.97392621796379 ,30.213185731350436],
                    [59.97588364471797 ,30.213700715481327],
                    [59.977840955392935,30.21593231338173 ],
                    [59.979475543472134,30.22099632400188 ],
                    [59.98050787316514 ,30.229579392849537],
                    [59.98085197588536 ,30.236102525173756],
                    [59.981196075016896,30.24228233474406 ],
                    [59.9817982398529  ,30.24743217605266 ],
                    [59.98205630713642 ,30.252925340115123],
                    [59.982400393716816,30.258418504177666],
                    [59.98222835087971 ,30.263225022732346],
                    [59.98188426250503 ,30.26734489577919 ],
                    [59.98119607500791 ,30.272494737087786],
                    [59.98050787316514 ,30.276271287380787],
                ],
                 []
                    
                ],
            // Задаем правило заливки внутренних контуров по алгоритму "nonZero".
            fillRule: "nonZero"
        },
        // Описываем свойства геообъекта.
        properties:{
            // Содержимое балуна.
            //balloonContent: "Доставка - 550 руб123",
   
        }
    }, {
        // Описываем опции геообъекта.
        // Описываем опции геообъекта.
        // Цвет заливки.
        fillColor: '#2B345A',
        // Цвет обводки.
        strokeColor: '#D6EBFF',
        // Общая прозрачность (как для заливки, так и для обводки).
        opacity: 0.3,
        // Ширина обводки.
        strokeWidth: 1,
  balloonLayout: MyBalloonLayout,
  balloonContentLayout: BalloonContentLayout,
  
          
    });
 
// Добавляем многоугольник на карту.
    myMap.geoObjects.add(myGeoObject);

    myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark([59.941840, 30.434473], {
            hintContent: 'Мы находимся тут',
        }, {
            iconColor: '#FD7669'
        });

    myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);

}
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,500,600,700&display=swap");

* {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 font-family: 'Montserrat';
 min-width: 320px;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 position: relative;
 margin: 0;
}

.clear{
 clear: both;
}

.clearfix:after{
 content: ".";
 display: block;
 height: 0;
 clear: both;
 visibility: hidden;
}

a {
 display: inline-block;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff;
}

a:hover, a:focus, a:active {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff;
 outline: none;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p {
 margin: 0;
 line-height: normal;
}

ul {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

input,
button,
textarea,
select {
 outline: none;
}

img {
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}

.container {
 width: 1200px;
 margin: auto;
}

.btn {
 background-color: #FD7669;
 -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 padding: 13px 30px;
 line-height: 1;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: 700;
 -webkit-transition: .12s;
 transition: .12s;
 border: 0px;
 color: #fff !important;
 font-family: 'Montserrat';
 cursor: pointer;
}

.btn:hover {
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #D9D9D9;
     box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #D9D9D9;
 -webkit-transform: translateY(-2px);
   -ms-transform: translateY(-2px);
     transform: translateY(-2px);
}

.s-title {
 font-size: 30px;
 font-weight: 700;
 line-height: 1.1;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
 text-align: center;
}

/
/* Contacts section */
.contacts {
 padding-top: 40px;
 padding-bottom: 80px;
}

.contacts-box {
 width: 365px;
 height: 101%;
 background-color: #fff;
 padding: 25px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
     border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
 display: inline-block;
 position: absolute;
 left: -3px;
 top: -2px;
}

.contacts-text {
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: 500;
 color: #666;
 line-height: 1.6;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.contacts-link {
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: 500;
 color: #666;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.contacts-link a {
 color: #FD7669;
 font-weight: 700;
}

.contacts-link a:hover, .contacts-link a:focus, .contacts-link a:active {
 color: #FD7669;
}

.contacts-wrapper {
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 12px #C4C4C4;
     box-shadow: 0 0 12px #C4C4C4;
 -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
     border-radius: 10px;
 position: relative;
 background-color: #fff;
 height: 375px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.contacts-btn {
 border: 1px solid #2B345A;
 -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
     border-radius: 8px;
 padding: 12px 30px;
 font-size: 18px;
 font-weight: 700;
 line-height: 1;
 color: #2B345A;
 margin-top: 20px;
 -webkit-transition: .12s;
 transition: .12s;
}

.contacts-btn:hover {
 background-color: rgba(214, 235, 255, 0.5);
 color: #2B345A;
}

.contacts-btn:focus, .contacts-btn:active {
 background-color: #D6EBFF;
 color: #2B345A;
}

.contacts-btn-wrapper {
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Доставка</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
 <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&amp;apikey=619a9b44-535b-45be-aa39-887620068816" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="js_2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <style>
 #map{
  height: 385px;
  width: calc(100% - 365px);
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  }
 .my-hint{
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 193px;
  height: 40px;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
 }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="contacts">
  <div class="container contacts-container">
      <div class="contacts-title s-title">Контакты</div>
   <div class="contacts-wrapper">
    <div id="map"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему, код основан на примере из песочницы:
https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/balloon_autopan

Вернул пару необходимых ссылок:

```
<link href="https://yandex.st/bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://yandex.st/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

и пару используемых стилей:

```
.popover {
    display: block;
}
.popover .close {
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    top: 1px;
}
```

из примера. Так код работает без ошибок.

```js
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {
  var myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
      center: [59.951671, 30.330581],
      zoom: 10
    }, {
      searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
    }),

    // Создание макета балуна на основе Twitter Bootstrap.
    MyBalloonLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
      '<div class="popover top">' +
      '<a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>' +
      '<div class="arrow"></div>' +
      '<div class="popover-inner">' +
      '$[[options.contentLayout observeSize minWidth=235 maxWidth=235 maxHeight=350]]' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>', {
        /**
         * Строит экземпляр макета на основе шаблона и добавляет его в родительский HTML-элемент.
         * @see https://api.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/layout.templateBased.Base.xml#build
         * @function
         * @name build
         */
        build: function() {
          this.constructor.superclass.build.call(this);

          this._$element = $('.popover', this.getParentElement());

          this.applyElementOffset();

          this._$element.find('.close')
            .on('click', $.proxy(this.onCloseClick, this));
        },

        /**
         * Удаляет содержимое макета из DOM.
         * @see https://api.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/layout.templateBased.Base.xml#clear
         * @function
         * @name clear
         */
        clear: function() {
          this._$element.find('.close')
            .off('click');

          this.constructor.superclass.clear.call(this);
        },

        /**
         * Метод будет вызван системой шаблонов АПИ при изменении размеров вложенного макета.
         * @see https://api.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/IBalloonLayout.xml#event-userclose
         * @function
         * @name onSublayoutSizeChange
         */
        onSublayoutSizeChange: function() {
          MyBalloonLayout.superclass.onSublayoutSizeChange.apply(this, arguments);

          if (!this._isElement(this._$element)) {
            return;
          }

          this.applyElementOffset();

          this.events.fire('shapechange');
        },

        /**
         * Сдвигаем балун, чтобы "хвостик" указывал на точку привязки.
         * @see https://api.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/IBalloonLayout.xml#event-userclose
         * @function
         * @name applyElementOffset
         */
        applyElementOffset: function() {
          this._$element.css({
            left: -(this._$element[0].offsetWidth / 2),
            top: -(this._$element[0].offsetHeight + this._$element.find('.arrow')[0].offsetHeight)
          });
        },

        /**
         * Закрывает балун при клике на крестик, кидая событие "userclose" на макете.
         * @see https://api.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/IBalloonLayout.xml#event-userclose
         * @function
         * @name onCloseClick
         */
        onCloseClick: function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();

          this.events.fire('userclose');
        },

        /**
         * Используется для автопозиционирования (balloonAutoPan).
         * @see https://api.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/ILayout.xml#getClientBounds
         * @function
         * @name getClientBounds
         * @returns {Number[][]} Координаты левого верхнего и правого нижнего углов шаблона относительно точки привязки.
         */
        getShape: function() {
          if (!this._isElement(this._$element)) {
            return MyBalloonLayout.superclass.getShape.call(this);
          }

          var position = this._$element.position();

          return new ymaps.shape.Rectangle(new ymaps.geometry.pixel.Rectangle([
            [position.left, position.top],
            [
              position.left + this._$element[0].offsetWidth,
              position.top + this._$element[0].offsetHeight + this._$element.find('.arrow')[0].offsetHeight
            ]
          ]));
        },

        /**
         * Проверяем наличие элемента (в ИЕ и Опере его еще может не быть).
         * @function
         * @private
         * @name _isElement
         * @param {jQuery} [element] Элемент.
         * @returns {Boolean} Флаг наличия.
         */
        _isElement: function(element) {
          return element && element[0] && element.find('.arrow')[0];
        }
      });

  BalloonContentLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
    '<div style="margin: 10px;">11111</div>');

  // Создаем многоугольник, используя класс GeoObject.
  var myGeoObject = new ymaps.GeoObject({
    // Описываем геометрию геообъекта.
    geometry: {
      // Тип геометрии - "Многоугольник".
      type: "Polygon",
      // Указываем координаты вершин многоугольника.
      coordinates: [
        // Координаты вершин внешнего контура.
        [
          [59.98050787316514, 30.276271287380787],
          [59.981411135142736, 30.28348106521282],
          [59.981626193875776, 30.287600938259637],
          [59.98188426251403, 30.291720811306554],
          [59.98188426251403, 30.297213975369072],
          [59.981196075016896, 30.303393784939374],
          [59.97981965695854, 30.31197685378703],
          [59.97878730573293, 30.31747001784952],
          [59.97689457792983, 30.32364982741985],
          [59.97448549461692, 30.327426377712822],
          [59.97173204119555, 30.33017295974407],
          [59.969150469982154, 30.332232896267502],
          [59.96605231800164, 30.334292832790936],
          [59.964374030930564, 30.334807816921803],
          [59.962609585874226, 30.33497947829875],
          [59.959166494762414, 30.335322801052666],
          [59.95606740577672, 30.336524430691316],
          [59.954259469567496, 30.33798355239539],
          [59.95210703552669, 30.33017295974407],
          [59.95098771437923, 30.324593964993053],
          [59.94969614286743, 30.321246568142495],
          [59.94780174662443, 30.31747001784952],
          [59.94780174662443, 30.31300682204876],
          [59.94676839379639, 30.309573594509676],
          [59.94422793069265, 30.307341996609296],
          [59.941428889282946, 30.306827012478433],
          [59.94022307529868, 30.301677171169832],
          [59.937983589740675, 30.29481071609172],
          [59.93712220873366, 30.290347520290933],
          [59.93626080527731, 30.286227647244065],
          [59.93501173038011, 30.280820313870045],
          [59.933331865599165, 30.27764457839641],
          [59.93057497940691, 30.272838059841728],
          [59.92816251538927, 30.27009147781046],
          [59.92488817551137, 30.267344895779214],
          [59.92187204927931, 30.26597160476359],
          [59.91971750499295, 30.264598313747967],
          [59.91868327387625, 30.26082176345499],
          [59.91868327386725, 30.258332673489193],
          [59.91902802117505, 30.25567192214642],
          [59.92001914963477, 30.251981202541867],
          [59.92161351138359, 30.24743217605266],
          [59.922302941304906, 30.241939011990166],
          [59.924026453231384, 30.23816246169719],
          [59.92523285813594, 30.234385911404217],
          [59.926094548979066, 30.23129600661905],
          [59.92816251538927, 30.227176133572183],
          [59.928679486783494, 30.222026292263585],
          [59.929541087802285, 30.21807808059364],
          [59.93117806789334, 30.21395820754677],
          [59.932125756161206, 30.21138328689247],
          [59.93464561326022, 30.2106537260404],
          [59.93750983293789, 30.20992416518835],
          [59.94028767356927, 30.207048837124447],
          [59.9436250802578, 30.204001847683518],
          [59.947812510508044, 30.203658524929523],
          [59.95055719613177, 30.204774323879725],
          [59.95322631871933, 30.206920091091686],
          [59.95580913521645, 30.20820755141876],
          [59.95843479162023, 30.210439149319214],
          [59.96123239250762, 30.21378654616985],
          [59.963212089909675, 30.21618980544715],
          [59.96656869684799, 30.21618980544715],
          [59.96966680036843, 30.21515983718547],
          [59.972011699266595, 30.21361488479285],
          [59.97392621796379, 30.213185731350436],
          [59.97588364471797, 30.213700715481327],
          [59.977840955392935, 30.21593231338173],
          [59.979475543472134, 30.22099632400188],
          [59.98050787316514, 30.229579392849537],
          [59.98085197588536, 30.236102525173756],
          [59.981196075016896, 30.24228233474406],
          [59.9817982398529, 30.24743217605266],
          [59.98205630713642, 30.252925340115123],
          [59.982400393716816, 30.258418504177666],
          [59.98222835087971, 30.263225022732346],
          [59.98188426250503, 30.26734489577919],
          [59.98119607500791, 30.272494737087786],
          [59.98050787316514, 30.276271287380787],
        ],
        []

      ],
      // Задаем правило заливки внутренних контуров по алгоритму "nonZero".
      fillRule: "nonZero"
    },
    // Описываем свойства геообъекта.
    properties: {
      // Содержимое балуна.
      //balloonContent: "Доставка - 550 руб123",

    }
  }, {
    // Описываем опции геообъекта.
    // Описываем опции геообъекта.
    // Цвет заливки.
    fillColor: '#2B345A',
    // Цвет обводки.
    strokeColor: '#D6EBFF',
    // Общая прозрачность (как для заливки, так и для обводки).
    opacity: 0.3,
    // Ширина обводки.
    strokeWidth: 1,
    balloonLayout: MyBalloonLayout,
    balloonContentLayout: BalloonContentLayout,


  });

  // Добавляем многоугольник на карту.
  myMap.geoObjects.add(myGeoObject);

  myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark([59.941840, 30.434473], {
    hintContent: 'Мы находимся тут',
  }, {
    iconColor: '#FD7669'
  });

  myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);

}
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,500,600,700&display=swap");
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  min-width: 320px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

a:hover,
a:focus,
a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  outline: none;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: normal;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

input,
button,
textarea,
select {
  outline: none;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.container {
  width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
}

.btn {
  background-color: #FD7669;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 13px 30px;
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  -webkit-transition: .12s;
  transition: .12s;
  border: 0px;
  color: #fff !important;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn:hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #D9D9D9;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #D9D9D9;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-2px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-2px);
  transform: translateY(-2px);
}

.s-title {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1.1;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

/
/* Contacts section */

.contacts {
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 80px;
}

.contacts-box {
  width: 365px;
  height: 101%;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 25px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -3px;
  top: -2px;
}

.contacts-text {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #666;
  line-height: 1.6;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.contacts-link {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #666;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.contacts-link a {
  color: #FD7669;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.contacts-link a:hover,
.contacts-link a:focus,
.contacts-link a:active {
  color: #FD7669;
}

.contacts-wrapper {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 12px #C4C4C4;
  box-shadow: 0 0 12px #C4C4C4;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 375px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.contacts-btn {
  border: 1px solid #2B345A;
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 12px 30px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #2B345A;
  margin-top: 20px;
  -webkit-transition: .12s;
  transition: .12s;
}

.contacts-btn:hover {
  background-color: rgba(214, 235, 255, 0.5);
  color: #2B345A;
}

.contacts-btn:focus,
.contacts-btn:active {
  background-color: #D6EBFF;
  color: #2B345A;
}

.contacts-btn-wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Доставка</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <link href="https://yandex.st/bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://yandex.st/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&amp;apikey=619a9b44-535b-45be-aa39-887620068816" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js_2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <style>
    #map {
      height: 385px;
      width: calc(100% - 365px);
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
    }
    
    .my-hint {
      background: #FFFFFF;
      border-radius: 4px;
      width: 193px;
      height: 40px;
      font-family: Montserrat;
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 18px;
    }
    
    .popover {
      display: block;
    }
    
    .popover .close {
      position: absolute;
      right: 5px;
      top: 1px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="contacts">
    <div class="container contacts-container">
      <div class="contacts-title s-title">Контакты</div>
      <div class="contacts-wrapper">
        <div id="map"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```